# Groups in Atwho (At.js)?

Tags: javascript

My task at the moment is to implement a 'mention user' mechanism for our service to allow our users to mention each other in comments.
[Atwho (At.js)](https://github.com/ichord/At.js/) fitted perfectly. But there is one issue that has to be addressed in the nearest future: grouping elements of the drop-down list like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) allows us to. By now I've tried the following: I insert group label tag (the same ***li*** tag with a different class) in the first element of each group:

```
var at_config = {
            ...,
            displayTpl: '<li class="${groupname}"></li><li class="option">${name} <small>${email}</small></li>',
            ...
        };
```

, where *groupname* is set to be not null only for the first element in each group. However, this leads to an unpleasant (though, not unexpected) behaviour: click on the group label tag is treated as if user chose the first element from that group. Is there a simple way to address this issue, not having to modify much At.js code?
Thanks in advance.